# Create timeseries dataset for TensorFlow v2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, time-series

I'm trying to feed a model CNN+LSTM with data from a csv. What I'm missing is setting a correct dataset to start training my model.

This is my test model:

```
def test_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(32, 4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="valid"), input_shape=[None, 6, 20]))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2), input_shape=[None, 6, 20]))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="valid"), input_shape=[None, 6, 20]))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2), input_shape=[None, 6, 20]))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(), input_shape=[None, 6, 20]))
    model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
```

Here you can download [test.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/15852f3357f03e982baf55f6253e868f/test.csv)

CSV dataset is made of 6 features + 1 multilabel. I need to create a time series each 20 row, so I think my shape should be [None, 6, 20] ordered by ascending timestamp value.

I'm new in TensorFlow and I don't know how to create an appropriate dataset from scratch, I was able to load a dataset from directory with images (for CNN) but in this scenario I really don't know how to do it.

This is what I tried to generate my dataset:

```
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    dataset = list()
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    count = 0
    timeseries = list()
    labels = list()
    for row in reader:
        count = count + 1
        if count <= 20:
            timeseries.append(
                [float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2]), float(row[3]), float(row[4]), float(row[5])])
        else:
            dataset.append(timeseries)
            labels.append(int(row[6].split("L")[-1]))
            timeseries = list()
            count = 0
```

After that I transformed it in a tf.DataSet like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)
```

Here I got a `<TensorSliceDataset shapes: (20, 6), types: tf.float32>` like I want. Then I fed a K-Fold with it:

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=test_model, epochs=60, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, dataset, labels, cv=kfold)
```

When running cross_val_score I got this error:

> TypeError: Singleton array array(<TensorSliceDataset shapes: (20, 6), types: tf.float32>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.

What I'm missing?

Comment: cross_val_score is from sklearn, it doesn't know what is a TensorSliceDataset... you have to use simply numpy arrays or something castable to numpy array

Comment: I see, after I made the dataset as np.array I got this error: `Input 0 of layer conv1d_4 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 6]`. I think this is due to TimeDistributed

Comment: This error is related to your model structure which doesn't match your data shape... the timeseries must be rehsape in 3D (n_sample, timestamps, features). In this sense the TimeDistributed seems useles

Comment: I see, maybe I'm too new to this and I don't know how to do it. My CSV is made of n_sample = 20, features = 6, and for timestamps each row has is own timestamp. How can I generate an appropriate dataset from that csv? 
My goal is to extract, with CNN, spatial features, and, with LSTM, temporal features for classify an unseen data